# Installing PEAR in Windows Server 2008, PLESK

Tags: php, pear

I'm not one to normally reach out but I've found myself completely stumped by this one.

I have a new server and chose to go with Windows Server 2008 and Plesk. After importing my site, I find that my includes no longer work, coming up with this error message:

require_once(include/online_class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'include/online_class.php

I have disabled open_basedir to make sure that it isn't conflicting but I am still getting this message. I have tried doing a fresh install of PEAR via command line and have made sure include_path points to the correct directory -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\PEAR

I have switched between both PHP 5.2 and 5.3 - 5.3 will just display a 500 error message without even reaching the php include errors.

Is there something I'm missing here? This is an issue I've never had with linux / cpanel builds and it's leaving a sour taste in my mouth with regards to Windows servers. What can I do to fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!